# TSQL Recursive CTE - get child record id up to a certain point

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have the below recordset that I am trying to get a list of linked IDs from given the parent ID.

```
DECLARE @TableVals TABLE 
                   ([ID] NVARCHAR(5), 
                    [NewId] NVARCHAR(5), 
                    [LinkDate] DATETIME, 
                    [IsUnlink] BIT);

INSERT INTO @TableVals 
VALUES ('00899', '00897', '01 Jan 2012 13:46:30', 0),
       ('00900', '00903', '01 Jan 2012 12:05:16', 0),
       ('00901', '00903', '01 Jan 2012 11:03:13', 1),
       ('00903', '00897', '01 Jan 2012 11:01:57', 0),
       ('00902', '00903', '01 Jan 2012 10:44:00', 0),
       ('00898', '00906', '01 Jan 2012 10:34:36', 1),
       ('00895', '00897', '01 Jan 2012 10:25:51', 0),
       ('00893', '00897', '01 Jan 2012 10:25:33', 0),
       ('00891', '00897', '01 Jan 2012 10:24:48', 0)
```

I have this CTE which returns two unexpected values (`00900` and `00902`), as these are linked to `00903` which was unlinked from. I've attempted to factor in a check on `LinkDate` but I suspect I've not got it quite right.

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(5) = '00897'

;WITH  CurrentLinks AS
(
   SELECT 
       [tv].[ID], [tv].[NewId], [tv].[LinkDate]
   FROM
       @TableVals [tv]
   WHERE 
       [tv].[NewId] = @ID
       AND [tv].[IsUnlink] != 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
       [tv].[ID], [tv].[NewId], [tv].[LinkDate]
   FROM 
       @TableVals [tv]
   INNER JOIN 
       CurrentLinks [cl] ON [tv].[NewId] = [cl].[ID]
                         AND [tv].[IsUnlink] != 1
)
SELECT 
    [cl].[ID]
FROM 
    CurrentLinks cl
WHERE 
    [cl].[id] != @ID
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM @TableVals tv 
                    WHERE (tv.ID = cl.ID OR tv.NewId = cl.ID) 
                      AND tv.LinkDate > cl.LinkDate)
ORDER BY 
    [cl].[LinkDate] DESC;
```

When ID is set to `00903` I expect `00900` and `00902` to be returned, and when ID `00897` is passed in I expect `00899`, `00895`, `00893` and `00891`.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction

Comment: what is your desired final output?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to achive... why can't it be simply `SELECT * FROM @TableVals WHERE [NewId] = '00897'` why don't you want `00903` WHEN ID is `00897 `?

Comment: I am also not sure exactly what is happening here but I have a comment.  You could null the link field and move the value to an archive field (UsedToBeLinkedTo)  rather than trying to incorporate the IsUnlinked field.  I only suggest this as a standard cte of a hierarchy is well documented.

Comment: Yes, I think it is going to have to result in a schema change. Or alternative other than CTE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is fine but your expectations of the expected result is wrong because of your dataset.

This record

```
('00903', '00897', '01 Jan 2012 11:01:57', 0),
```

links `00903` to `00897` and then `00903` links to `00900, 00901, and 00902` so you ware appropriately getting those as results when you use recursion.....

Comment: yeah I just had to stare at it and play with the query for a few minutes information overload had to sift through.......

Comment: hmmm I just moved your not exists into the cte and didn't get your desired results but then again I am still a little confused because you haven't specified how you want to limit the link date......can you post your new code and an explanation

Answer (score 0):

could something like this work?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @TableVals tv1
WHERE   [NewId] = @ID
        AND tv1.IsUnlink <> 1
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   @TableVals tv2
                         WHERE  tv2.[NewId] = tv1.[ID]
                                AND tv2.IsUnlink = 1 )
```

Comment: No, because if the record that unlinks `00903` wasn't there then then IDs `00900` and `00902` would not be returned. It probably requires a schema change. To make it easier to work with.

Comment: what wouldn't they?.. if the NewId = `00903` it would return them.. are you saying none of the records would be in the table?

Comment: This works for the current dataset. But when I remove the records `WHERE IsUnlink = 1` - i.e. so that `00903` is still linked - I still only get four records returned. Here, having removed the unlink records I would expect to see all six returned. I don't think it is easily doable.